# how to grab each value from input with jquery ajax when inputs are in a foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, input

Input fields and delete buttons are produced by a php foreach loop!

To grab the value of an input and send it to php i use code below:
Html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="file_id" id="<?php echo $file_id; ?>" value="<?php echo $file_id; ?>" />
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete" type="submit" name="delete_file">Delete</button>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).on('click' , '.delete' , function() {   
    var file_id = $('#<?php echo $file_id; ?>').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "admin.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {         
            file_id : file_id
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.result').html(data);            
        }
    });
});
```

php:

```
if(isset($_POST["file_id"])) {
    echo $_POST["file_id"];
}
```

Problem: When i submit (delete),it grabs always the value from the **first** input field. 
How can i make this work, so when i choose the second delete, that it grabs the value from the second input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
var file_id = $('#<?php echo $file_id; ?>').val();
```

use

```
var file_id = $(this).prev().val();  // according to provided markup
```

This will select previous element to the `<button>` (which is the hidden `<input>`), and takes its value.

Comment: Works great now! Thnx